# Passing Data between ViewController in swift4

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

[image]

In this above Picture Two views are there. Top one is a view for showing date(for this view the class name is **calender view**) . And the bottom one is a tableview.the current view name is **Main View** When i am clicking on the cell of the tableview then it will go to the **next view**. When i am dismising the **next view** i want to pass some data to the **calender view**.How to achive this.

```
class MainView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextVC") as! NextVC
        self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

}


class NextVC: UIViewController {

    var sendingData: String?

    @IBAction func backAction(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}


class CalenderView: UIViewController{

    var receiveValue: String?
}
```

Here i want when i am dismissing the **nextview** the value of  **sendingData** will pass to  **calender view**.

How to do this ? Please help.

Comment: There are a few approaches.

1) You could use a global variable and set its value, so it becomes available to all view controllers.
2) Use segue to go to Calendar View, and implement override function for prepareForSegue.

Comment: Show us relation between `CalendarView` and other controllers. Is it some child view controller or some new view controller somewhere and how do you present it? Add this to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can give you two solutions:

1. You can create your on custom notification.

First of all on back action you should post your notification with **sendingData**.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: UpdateCalendarNotification), object: sendingData)
```

Next, on main view controller with calendar view you should register notification for "UpdateCalendarNotification" name.

```
    func registerNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(updateCalendarView(_:)),
                                               name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "UpdateCalendarNotification"),
                                               object: nil)
    }
```

And on selector `updateCalendarView(_:)` you should handle changes for calendar view.

```
    @objc
    func updateCalendarView(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        if let sendingData = notification.object as? String {
            /// Update calendar view
        }
    }
```

2. Second solution is public block for you "next controller".

On next view controller you should add this handler:

```
    var onDismiss: ((String?) -> Void)?
```

and in `backAction` method you should pass your data

```
    onDismiss?(sendingData)
```

In your main view controller you should implement this block like this:

```
let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextVC") as! NextVC
next.onDismiss = { [weak self] (sendingData) in
    self?.calendarView.receiveValue = sendingData
}
self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I hope this will help you)